# Sunspot solr search, how to return top 3 articles by date?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, solr, sunspot, sunspot-rails

I am using solr via sunspot in my rails application where I want to list the top 3 articles by date sort by likes descending.

I have Article table with fields `title, content, published_at, likes`

**Searchable block :**

```
searchable do
  text(:title)
  date(:published_at)
  integer(:likes)
end
```

**Data:**

```
title       | published_at  | likes
-------------------------------------
Article 1   | 25th Dec 2017 | 2
Article 2   | 25th Dec 2017 | 3
Article 3   | 25th Dec 2017 | 1
Article 4   | 25th Dec 2017 | 3
Article 5   | 25th Dec 2017 | 6
Article 6   | 26th Dec 2017 | 0
Article 7   | 26th Dec 2017 | 4
Article 8   | 26th Dec 2017 | 6
Article 9   | 26th Dec 2017 | 8
Article 10  | 26th Dec 2017 | 2
Article 11  | 27th Dec 2017 | 9
Article 12  | 27th Dec 2017 | 5
Article 13  | 27th Dec 2017 | 4
Article 14  | 27th Dec 2017 | 6
Article 15  | 27th Dec 2017 | 1
```

**Expected O/P:**

```
25th Dec

Article 5
Article 2
Article 4

26th Dec

Article 9
Article 8
Article 7

27th Dec

Article 11
Article 14
Article 12
```

Any help would be much appreciated.